# How to automate Hive query

Tags: mysql, hadoop, hive, apache-pig

I have created a script of hive queries mainly for features creation and scoring for cross sell project. Most of the queries are simple queries that do the data cleaning , transformation etc. I want to automate this process so that I can start with hive table as input and can output the final result into Hbase file . My question are :

What is the best way to do it ?

Can I simply create `filename.sql` or `filename.hql` and run it from shell using `hive -f filename.sql`

Is there something in hive like PL for SQL?

Comment: we call the scripting in hive as hive query lanquage. you can run hive scripts  from command line hive -e 'command' or hive -f /pathtohql'. Finally use a cronjob or oozie coordinator job to schedule it .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it in multiple ways.
Like you can also use Hive CLI and its very ease to do such jobs.
You can write shell script in Linux or .bat in Windows.

In script you can simply go like below entries.

```
$HIVE_HOME/bin/hive -e 'select a.col from tab1 a';
```

or if you have file :

```
$HIVE_HOME/bin/hive -f /home/my/hive-script.sql
```

Make sure you have set $HIVE_HOME in your env.
Once you have tested and working fine you can put in cronjob for scheduling.

Answer (score 1):

It is important to note that if you are using either of the technique, each of your queries must be separated by a semi colon i.e.

```
hive -e 'select * from tableA limit 10;select * from tableB limit 10'
```